# Under what conditions will BlockingQueue.take throw interrupted exception?

Tags: java, concurrency, interrupted-exception

Let us suppose that I have a thread that consumes items produced by another thread. Its run method is as follows, with inQueue being a BlockingQueue

```
boolean shutdown = false;
while (!shutdown) {
    try {
        WorkItem w = inQueue.take();
        w.consume();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
        shutdown = true;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, a different thread will signal that there are no more work items by interrupting this running thread. Will take() throw an interrupted exception if it does not need to block to retrieve the next work item. i.e. if the producer signals that it is done filling the work queue, is it possible to accidentally leave some items in inQueue or miss the interrupt?

Comment: You've almost got it right. Rather than having the *consumer* set "shutdown" to true upon interruption, instead have the *producer* set it to true before interrupting the consumer. Note this A) keeps things pretty by avoiding a sentinel value ("poison pill"), B) correctly handles spurious wakeups, and C) is more general in that you can deliberately halt the consumer whether or not the queue is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good way to signal termination of a blocking queue is to submit a 'poison' value into the queue that indicates a shutdown has occurred.  This ensures that the expected behavior of the queue is honored.  Calling Thread.interupt() is probably not a good idea if you care about clearing the queue.

To provide some code:

```
boolean shutdown = false;
while (!shutdown) {
    try {
        WorkItem w = inQueue.take();
        if (w == QUEUE_IS_DEAD)
          shutdown = true;
        else
          w.consume();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
        // possibly submit QUEUE_IS_DEAD to the queue
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work best. From what I can tell in rare cases the 'done' interrupt can be delivered before take() wakes due to more stuff being in the queue. To guard against this, I had to drain the queue with a second loop anyway.

Answer (score 2):

According to [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29), the `take()` method will throw `InterruptedException` if interrupted while waiting.

Comment: What does it exactly mean?
""if interrupted while waiting""
EDIT: Nevermind. I understood from FkYkko's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I wondered about the same thing and reading the javadoc for [take()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) I believed that it would throw an interrupted exception only after having taken all the items in the queue, since if the queue had items, it would not have to "wait".
But I made a small test:

```
package se.fkykko.slask;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class BlockingQueueTakeTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Runner t = new Runner();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(t);
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        t.queue.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println(("Number of items in queue: " + t.queue.size()));
    t1.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    t1.interrupt();
    t1.join();
    System.out.println(("Number of items in queue: " + t.queue.size()));
    System.out.println(("Joined t1. Finished"));

}

private static final class Runner implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(100);
    AtomicLong m_count = new AtomicLong(0);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                queue.take();
                System.out.println("Took item " + m_count.incrementAndGet());
                final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) < 100) {
                    Thread.yield(); //Spin wait
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted. Count: " + m_count.get());
        }
    }
}

}
```

The runner will take 10-11 items and then finish i.e. take() will throw InterruptedException even if there still is items in the queue.

Summary: Use the Poison pill approach instead, then you have full control over how much is left in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't in general interrupt the threads of an `ExecutorService` from external code if you used `ExecutorService::execute(Runnable)` to start the threads, because external code does not have a reference to the `Thread` objects of each of the running threads (see the end of this answer for a solution though, if you need `ExecutorService::execute`). However, if you instead use `ExecutorService::submit(Callable<T>)` to submit the jobs, you get back a `Future<T>`, which internally keeps a reference to the running thread once `Callable::call()` begins execution. This thread can be interrupted by calling `Future::cancel(true)`. Any code within (or called by) the `Callable` that checks the current thread's interrupt status can therefore be interrupted via the `Future` reference. This includes `BlockingQueue::take()`, which, even when blocked, will respond to thread interruption. (JRE blocking methods will typically wake up if interrupted while blocked, realize they have been interrupted, and throw an `InterruptedException`.)

To summarize: `Future::cancel()` and `Future::cancel(true)` both *cancel future work*, while `Future::cancel(true)` also *interrupts ongoing work* (as long as the ongoing work responds to thread interrupt). Neither of the two `cancel` invocations affects work that has already successfully completed.

Note that once a thread is interrupted by cancellation, an `InterruptException` will be thrown within the thread (e.g. by `BlockingQueue::take()` in this case). However, you a `CancellationException` will be thrown back in the main thread the next time you call `Future::get()` on a successfully cancelled `Future` (i.e. a `Future` that was cancelled before it completed). This is different from what you would normally expect: if a non-cancelled `Callable` throws `InterruptedException`, the next call to `Future::get()` will throw `InterruptedException`, but if a cancelled `Callable` throws `InterruptedException`, the next call to `Future::get()` will through `CancellationException`.

Here's an example that illustrates this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Start Executor with 4 threads
        int numThreads = 4;
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
        try {
            // Set up BlockingQueue for inputs, and List<Future> for outputs
            BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>();
            List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>(numThreads);
            for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
                int threadIdx = i;
                futures.add(executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call() throws Exception {
                        try {
                            // Get an input from the queue (blocking)
                            int val = queue.take();
                            return "Thread " + threadIdx + " got value " + val;
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // Thrown once Future::cancel(true) is called
                            System.out.println("Thread " + threadIdx + " got interrupted");
                            // This value is returned to the Future, but can never
                            // be read, since the caller will get a CancellationException
                            return "Thread " + threadIdx + " got no value";
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }

            // Enqueue (numThreads - 1) values into the queue, so that one thread blocks
            for (int i = 0; i < numThreads - 1; i++) {
                queue.add(100 + i);
            }

            // Cancel all futures
            for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++) {
                Future<String> future = futures.get(i);
                // Cancel the Future -- this doesn't throw an exception until
                // the get() method is called
                future.cancel(/* mayInterruptIfRunning = */ true);
                try {
                    System.out.println(future.get());
                } catch (CancellationException e) {
                    System.out.println("Future " + i + " was cancelled");
                }
            }
        } finally {
            // Terminate main after all threads have shut down (this call does not block,
            // so main will exit before the threads stop running)
            executor.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Each time you run this, the output will be different, but here's one run:

```
Future 1 was cancelled
Future 0 was cancelled
Thread 2 got value 100
Thread 3 got value 101
Thread 1 got interrupted
```

This shows that Thread 2 and Thread 3 completed before `Future::cancel()` was called. Thread 1 was cancelled, so internally `InterruptedException` was thrown, and externally `CancellationException` was thrown. Thread 0 was cancelled before it started running. (Note that the thread indices won't in general correlate with the `Future` indices, so `Future 0 was cancelled` could correspond to either thread 0 or thread 1 being cancelled, and the same for `Future 1 was cancelled`.)

**Advanced:** one way to achieve the same effect with `Executor::execute` (which does not return a `Future` reference) rather than `Executor::submit` would be to create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a custom `ThreadFactory`, and have your `ThreadFactory` record a reference in a concurrent collection (e.g. a concurrent queue) for every thread created. Then to cancel all threads, you can simply call `Thread::interrupt()` on all previously-created threads. However, you will need to deal with the race condition that new threads may be created while you are interrupting existing threads. To handle this, set an `AtomicBoolean` flag, visible to the `ThreadFactory`, that tells it not to create any more threads, then once that is set, cancel the existing threads.

Answer (score -1):

The java.concurrency.utils package was designed and implemented by some of the finest minds in concurrent programming.  Also, interrupting threads as a means to terminate them is explicitly endorsed by their book "Java Concurrency in Practice".  Therefore, I would be extremely surprised if any items were left in the queue due to an interrupt.

Comment: Try it in a test and be "extremely surprised" ;-)

Comment: "Smart people made it" plus "interrupt() interrupts threads" does not entail "blocking queues don't check interrupt status until they're empty". For example, at least one implementation (cf. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java#ArrayBlockingQueue.take) of ArrayBlockingQueue calls ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(), which checks the thread's interrupt status (throwing an InterruptedException if interrupted) before trying to get the next element.