# Java thread executor never shuts down?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I've following code that puts some data into a blocking queue, and submits thread tasks to Java executor service based on a fixed thread pool. When I attempt to shutdown the executor though it doesn't shut down, any idea please?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ThreadExecutir {
    public static ArrayBlockingQueue<String> files;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        shutdownExec();
    }

    private static void shutdownExec() {
        int size = 10;
        files = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            files.add("Java " + i);
        }

        ThreadExecutir outer = new ThreadExecutir();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 * size; i++) {
            executor.submit(outer.new myThread());
        }
        System.out.println(executor.isShutdown());
        executor.shutdown();

        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            System.out.println("Awaiting for threads to complete!");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (files.isEmpty())
            executor.shutdownNow();
        System.out.println(executor.isShutdown());

    }

    class myThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {

            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + "started running! ");
            try {
                String uploadThis = files.take();
                System.out.println("I'm working " + threadName + " "
                        + uploadThis);
                // this.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                System.out.println("Thread " + threadName
                        + " finished running! ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After a few `myThread` instances have consumed all the elements in `files`, the rest block on the `files.take()`.

The javadoc of [`shutdown`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) states

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are
>   executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no
>   additional effect if already shut down.

You've submitted all your 30 tasks (10 of which are executing), before calling `shutdown`. So they all need to finish execution before the `ExecutorService` can be considered terminated. But most of them can't finish executing since nothing exists, at the moment, to get them to stop blocking at the `take()`.

You need to either submit more items to the `ArrayBlockingQueue` or interrupt the threads in the `ExecutorService`. [`shutdownNow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--) can be used to interrupt those threads.

Note that an interrupt might not be enough to stop your threads, since the interrupt might arrive before the blocking call. You'll need a more [sophisticated solution, like a poison pill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956526/under-what-conditions-will-blockingqueue-take-throw-interrupted-exception).

---

Although you've subclassed `Thread`,

```
class myThread extends Thread {
```

you're only using `myThread` as a `Runnable` (`Thread` implements `Runnable`). This is pretty pointless. Just implement `Runnable`

```
class myThread implements Runnable {
```

Comment: I added a poison pill to the queue, but threads still don't die on their own! Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You submitted only 5 strings into a queue and 30 tasks. First 5 tasks consume all 5 strings from `files` and next one is blocked trying to `poll()` string from empty queue (`notEmpty.await()` is called on the queue).

Thread will wait until it will be interrupted. Executor will wait until its threads are finished.

So the code will stuck on `executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)` and never reach `if (files.isEmpty()) executor.shutdownNow();`

Looks like you have to use `files.poll()` instead of `files.take()` - it won't lock in empty queue `return (count == 0) ? null : dequeue();`.